# Get HttpPost response string in HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-post, dotnet-httpclient

I have an web api that do a POST and return a string:

```
[HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody] Property p)
    {
        // My code where I'll get success and/or Error string message
        if(success)
            return string.Format("OK");
        else
            return string.Format(Error);
    }
```

I have a .net that calls this HttpPost:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData);
var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

var result = client.PostAsync("", byteContent).Result;
var contents = result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
```

I expect to have in the variable contents the value "OK" or Error string. However contents receive an System.IO.MemoryStream

If I run in the Postman, I get the "OK" as return.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ReadAsStringAsync` method:

```
var contents = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. BTW, the return was "\"OK\"" instead of just OK. Any idea why?

Comment: Calling `.Result` may lead to deadlocks. Better use [AsyncBridge](https://github.com/tejacques/AsyncBridge) instead.